# Excel: how to automatically sort scatter plot (or make proportional X-axis on line chart)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

In Excel, I have a table with "years" column not sorted (it's a calculation result) and a "value" columns and I want to draw a chart of these values.

Scatter plot xy require ordered x numbers.

Line chart doesn't plot x values proportionally.
How can I do ?

[image: Exemple of my table with scatter plot and line charts]

(I use MS Excel 365)

Comment: I think if you right-click on the axis labels and choose "Format Axis", then select "Date Axis" from the Axis Options, you will get the desired result

Comment: Yes it works in the line chart ! Thanks a lot !
I will add your answer, with details, if you're agree.

Comment: Careful: the line chart with a date axis ignores the fractional parts of the X values.

Comment: Indeed. Not perfect but acceptable for my usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use the line chart specifying x-axis as a "date axis".

Double click the x-axis, on the side bar choose axis options icon [image: axis options icon] then select "Date axis" [image: Date axis].

Drawback of this method: the fractional parts of the X values are not displayed.

Specifying the number format of X-axis labels with "decimal places: 0" gives me an acceptable result.

[image: an acceptable result].

Answer (score 2):

A few formulas will fix the data for you. Columns A and B contain your original data. Columns C thru F have formulas in these cells, copied down as far as needed:

C2: =RANK(A2,A$2:A$12,1)+COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)-1
D2: (not formulas, just values 1, 2, 3, etc.)
E2: =INDEX(A$2:A$12,MATCH($D2,$C$2:$C$12,0))
F2: =INDEX(B$2:B$12,MATCH($D2,$C$2:$C$12,0))

Just plot columns E and F in your chart.

[image: Sorted Data]

If you have the new **Dynamic Arrays**, it's even easier. Columns A and B have the original data. These formulas are only entered into the indicated cells, and they fill values down automagically:

C2: =SORT(A2:A12)
D2: =SORTBY(B2:B12,A2:A12)

[image: Sorted Data with Dynamic Arrays]

Comment: Thank you. Really interesting.